# Using bash to read elements on a diagonal on a matrix and redirecting it to another file

Tags: bash, awk

So, currently i have created a code to do this as shown below. This code works and does what it is supposed to do after I echo the variables:

```
a=`awk 'NR==2 {print $1}' $coor`

b=`awk 'NR==3 {print $2}' $coor`

c=`awK 'NR==4 {print $3}' $coor`
```

....but i have to do this for many more lines and i want a more general expression. So I have attempted to create a loop shown below. Syntax wise i don't think anything is wrong with the code, but it is not outputting anything to the file "Cmain".

I was wondering if anyone could help me, I'm kinda new at scripting.

If it helps any, I can also post what i am trying to read.

```
for (( i=1; i <= 4 ; i++ )); do
  for (( j=0; j <= 3 ; j++ )); do
    B="`grep -n "cell" "$coor" | awk 'NR=="$i" {print $j}'`"
  done
done

echo "$B" >> Cmain
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace your lines of `awk` with this one:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (NR >= 2 && NR == i) print $(i - 1) }' file.txt
```

Tested input:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80
```

Output:

```
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
```

Comment: thanks!!!, i didnt know you could use awk like that....but now im curious why my second block of code doesnt do anything...even tho the syntax is right

Comment: @user1556318, would you be able to add some example input and desired output? It's difficult to tell what you're trying to accomplish, but perhaps I can help.

Answer (score 2):

`awk 'BEGIN {f=1} {print $f; f=f+1}' infile > outfile`

Comment: Shorter: `awk '{++f; print $f}' infile > outfile`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson / Vadim, how does this work? Is there a special meaning to variable `f`? What is it called?

Comment: @user13107: No there's no special meaning. The variable is being incremented and the field numbered with the value of the variable is printed. This answer works similarly to Steve's, but is faster.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using `sed` and `coreutils`, assuming space separated input is in `infile`:

```
n=$(wc -l infile | cut -d' ' -f1)
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
  sed -n "${i} {p; q}" infile | cut -d' ' -f$i
done
```